# C++ winapi and gtk wrapper (gui)

Tags: c++, api, user-interface, widget, gtk

I need a nice and possibly lightweight wrapper for winapi gui and gtk gui (what I mean is a GUI library which have its own abstract api, is available for windows and linux, and it uses winapi on windows to draw widgets and on linux it uses gtk). Pretty much how wxwidgets works, but since wxwidget macro C-style api is a mess, it's heavy weight and I can't get my app to compile with it, so I definetely don't want it. I also don't want QT (i don't want extra compiler and heavyweight dependencies). There is also fox toolkit and fltk, but they don't wrap winapi and gtk but have their own rendering, which I don't like.

I don't need many features, just few basic widgets and window managment, and that's it. There are many very nice libs that do this for python, but in C++ I can't find any (besides wx widgets which doesn't work and is too heavy).

Could anybody help me? Because I'm stuck with developing my game as I need to develop a crossplatform editor. If everything else fail I will just write it in python, but I really want to make it in C++.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) is close, but it is not C++.

Your requirements are too close to wxWidgets: I doubt anyone has started/will start a project that basically duplicates it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use GTKmm, the C++ bindings for GTK, with a Windows theme. But it's true that GTK theming may be hard to get right on several Windows versions.

Comment: Last gtkmm (and gtk) binaries for windows are for 2.2 and we have 3.4 now. Not to mention building it on mingw is a pain and I don't know all the tricks needed to compile it. But, gtkmm api is the best I've seen in c++ gui lib. So bad that there are no windows libs :(

Comment: You're right, GTK development on Windows is a bit behind nowadays. In fact GTK maintenance is done by GNOME developers, because they are almost the only ones that care enough about GTK. There's only 1 or 2  Windows developers coming at help. That's why there's currently no version of GTK 3 supported on Windows, and there's no official installer either. However, so people are trying to work on that. You can for example get an installer from http://www.tarnyko.net/en/ . But GTKmm future is a bit foggy: http://www.murrayc.com/blog/permalink/2012/11/08/gtkmm-maintainership/